# Generating random coordinates with differences between them

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, algorithm

So i seek to generate 5 random coordinates within an area of roughly 640,000 points with each axis value between 100 and 900. These coordinates must have a distance of more than 100 between them to prevent an overlap. Having searched previous answers and attempted a piece of code below:

```
struct point
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    };

    point pointarray[6];
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    pointarray[1].x = 100+(std::rand()% 801);
    pointarray[1].y = 100+(std::rand()% 801);
    for (int n=2; n <= 5 ; n++)
    {
        double dist;
        int currentx;
        int currenty;
        double xch;
        double ych;
        while (dist < 100)
        {
            srand ( time(NULL) );
            currentx = (100+(std::rand()% 801));
            currenty = (100+(std::rand()% 801));

            xch = (currentx - (pointarray[(n-1)].x));
            ych = (currenty - (pointarray[(n-1)].y));
            dist = sqrt(xch*xch + ych*ych);
            if (dist >= 100 && dist <= 800 )
            {
                currentx = pointarray[n].x;
                currenty = pointarray[n].y;
            }
        }
    }
```

I do not understand why the last 4 points are absolutely huge numbers (in the millions) while only the first is within the required range?

Comment: Array indices start at 0, and dist is not initialized so it's possible your while loop never executes.

Comment: Also, calling `srand` within the `while` loop probably does not do what you want - it should be enough to call it once before both loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use uninitialized `dist`, it could be the problem:

```
double dist;
....
while (dist < 100)
```

Also, I see no place where you write to pointarray (except pointarray[1]). Should not

```
currentx = pointarray[n].x;
```

become

```
pointarray[n].x = currentx;
```

Also, if `dist` gets bigger than `800`, then nothing happens and we just go to the next element. I guess the intention was to stay within `while` loop instead.

Also, we check the distance to one previous point. I'm not sure, but it could be that the intention was to check distances to all previous points. In the latter case, we need an inner loop perhaps. But make sure that there is no possibility that already placed points make it impossible to put the next one.

Also, perhaps you do not want the second `srand ( time(NULL) );`

Comment: Should i declare dist within the while loop?

Comment: @Vandib You could just initialize it to enter the while loop, e.g. `double dist = 0;`.

Comment: @Vandib It could be some more issues with the code. See my update. Good luck!